# find max and min in an efficient way

Tags: c

I have an array which is as follows

```
uint32_t arr1[] = {2, 34, 78, 5, 10, 100};
```

where `arr1[0]` indicates the number of ranges i.e. in the above example there are two ranges `34 to 78` and `5 to 10` and `100` is an individual value.

I want to find the maximum and minimum value from this array in an efficient way, in arr1 the maximum value is `100` and minimum value is `5`.

I was doing as follows:

```
max = arr1[1];
min = arr1[1];
int len = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);

for(int i = 2; i < len; i++){
  if(arr[i] < min)
     min = arr[i];
  if(arr[i] > max)
     max = arr[i];  
}
```

Another example is

```
uint32_t arr2[] = {1, 18, 39, 2};
```

In this example there is only one range i.e `18 to 39`  and `2` is an individual value, therefore the minimum value is `2` and maximum value is `39`

One more example is

```
uint32_t arr3[] = {0, 14, 5, 256, 99};
```

There is no ranges in this example, therefore minimum value is `5` and maximum value is `256`

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Hassan Imam: Problem is nothing, want to know if there is an efficient way to know the max and min value

Comment: Do you know about the dangers of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)?

Comment: Why do you think this might be inefficient?  You've got to examine every value in the array — and you do that.  If a value is a new minimum, it can't also be a new maximum; you could use an `else` in front of the second `if` in the loop.

Comment: I don't get why you care about "ranges" at all, and why their count would matter. If you want the minimum and the maximum you just iterate over the elements of the array you care about and do as you are doing - keep a running minimum and maximum. There's no smarter way, your code has to iterate over every element anyway.

Comment: The ranges allow the code to be optimized slightly, assuming the low value of the range always precedes the high value. But frankly, it's not worth it. The code you have is fine.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to compare the begin of a range only with the minimum value and the end of the range only with  the maximum value. But it does not look more efficient because you need more 'if' statements.

Comment: well, yes, for ranges the maximum can only be the range end, and minimum the range start... you *might* have a slight advantage with much longer arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unusual data structure in the arrays allows for some optimization.  While you're dealing with the ranges (pairs of values) identified by `arr[0]`, you need only test the first element of the pair against the minimum and the second element against the maximum.  When you're dealing with the non-range values, you have to check each element against both minimum and maximum.

That leads to code such as the following:

```
#undef NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void find_min_max(size_t num, uint32_t arr[num], uint32_t *pmin, uint32_t *pmax)
{
    assert(arr != 0 && pmin != 0 && pmax != 0 && num > 1);
    assert(arr[0] <= num);
    assert(arr[0] == 0 || num > 2);

    uint32_t max = arr[1];
    uint32_t min = arr[1];
    uint32_t lim = arr[0] * 2;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 1; i < lim; i += 2)
    {
        assert(arr[i] <= arr[i + 1]);
        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
        if (arr[i + 1] > max)
            max = arr[i + 1];
    }

    for ( ; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
        else if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    }
    *pmin = min;
    *pmax = max;
}

static void test_min_max(const char *tag, size_t num, uint32_t arr[num])
{
    uint32_t lim = arr[0] * 2;
    size_t i;

    printf("%s (%zu):\n", tag, num);
    for (i = 1; i < lim; i += 2)
        printf("  Range %zu: %" PRIu32 "..%" PRIu32 "\n", i / 2, arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
    while (i < num)
        printf("  Value: %" PRIu32 "\n", arr[i++]);

    uint32_t min;
    uint32_t max;
    find_min_max(num, arr, &min, &max);

    printf("%s: min = %" PRIu32 ", max = %" PRIu32 "\n", tag, min, max);
}

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t arr1[] = { 2, 34, 78, 5, 10, 100 };
    uint32_t arr2[] = { 1, 18, 39, 2 };
    uint32_t arr3[] = { 0, 14, 5, 256, 99 };
    uint32_t arr4[] = { 2, 9, 14, 5, 256 };
    uint32_t arr5[] = { 2, 9, 14, 5, 256, 2 };
    uint32_t arr6[] = { 2, 9, 14, 5, 256, 379 };
    uint32_t arr7[] = { 0, 9, };
    uint32_t arr8[] = { 1, 9, 9 };

    test_min_max("arr1", sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]), arr1);
    test_min_max("arr2", sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]), arr2);
    test_min_max("arr3", sizeof(arr3) / sizeof(arr3[0]), arr3);
    test_min_max("arr4", sizeof(arr4) / sizeof(arr4[0]), arr4);
    test_min_max("arr5", sizeof(arr5) / sizeof(arr5[0]), arr5);
    test_min_max("arr6", sizeof(arr6) / sizeof(arr6[0]), arr6);
    test_min_max("arr7", sizeof(arr7) / sizeof(arr7[0]), arr7);
    test_min_max("arr8", sizeof(arr8) / sizeof(arr8[0]), arr8);

    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produces the output:

```
arr1 (6):
  Range 0: 34..78
  Range 1: 5..10
  Value: 100
arr1: min = 5, max = 100
arr2 (4):
  Range 0: 18..39
  Value: 2
arr2: min = 2, max = 39
arr3 (5):
  Value: 14
  Value: 5
  Value: 256
  Value: 99
arr3: min = 5, max = 256
arr4 (5):
  Range 0: 9..14
  Range 1: 5..256
arr4: min = 5, max = 256
arr5 (6):
  Range 0: 9..14
  Range 1: 5..256
  Value: 2
arr5: min = 2, max = 256
arr6 (6):
  Range 0: 9..14
  Range 1: 5..256
  Value: 379
arr6: min = 5, max = 379
arr7 (2):
  Value: 9
arr7: min = 9, max = 9
arr8 (3):
  Range 0: 9..9
arr8: min = 9, max = 9
```

Whether this more complicated code really buys significant efficiency over simply scanning the values (as shown in the question) is debatable — or measurable, but the measurement requires vastly bigger numbers of elements in the arrays to be detectable.  On the array sizes shown, there'll be essentially no measurable difference.

Comment: Already printing out additional console output makes it inefficient.

Comment: @tangoal: The printing is to prove that it is working correctly.  Any printing makes the efficiency of the calculation largely irrelevant.  The refactored code separates the printing from the calculation.  That allows the efficiency of the code that finds the minimum and maximum to be measured sensibly (as long as you're careful).

Comment: This is broken if I pass in a 0 or 1-sized array. Even if we say that the first case is a contract violation, the second one should at least avoid UB. Either initialize `min` with `-1` and `max` with 0, or do an early return.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: There comes a point at which GIGO (Garbage In, Garbage Out) is a valid response.  I've upgraded the assertions to cover the minimal cases; the code has `#undef NDEBUG` so assertions are always in effect. If you don't want assertions, you need to know the policies of product in which it is being used. The `find_min_max()` function could return a bool (true the result is OK, false it's not). It's fairly clearly a homework exercise; the whole thing is overkill, but overkill is sometimes the name of the game. Using `-1` with `uint32_t` is icky; you probably had `UINT32_MAX` in mind.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: honestly I did have `-1` in mind, it's guaranteed (and established practice) that -1 casted to an unsigned type is its maximum value. For the rest, the point is that in general any well designed algorithm implementation should at very least not go into UB-land on an empty range; for such a case (where sensible min/max values on an empty ranges do not really exist) providing either `min > max` (cheap to write and good as a flag for the caller), or just not touching them (the caller is responsible to check at least later that the range is empty) are both acceptable.

Comment: Minor: I'd expect `&& num > 0` to be sufficient vs `&& num > 1`